# How to use string::find to find either "+" or "-" in one operation

Tags: c++, string, stl, find

I want to find the location of `+` or `-` in a complex number , e.g.

```
x + y*i 

x - y*i
```

Usually , I will do this :

```
int found = str.find("+");
if (found != string::npos)
    cout << "'+' also found at: " << found << endl;


found = str.find("-");
if (found != string::npos)
    cout << "'-' also found at: " << found << endl;
```

How can I give `find` multiple options to find in a single run ?

Comment: Couldn't you just check the documentation of `std::string`?

Comment: @KirilKirov: Sorry for posting this post , would you ever forgive me ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`std::string::find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of):

```
size_t found = str.find_first_of("+-");
```

which (from the linked reference page):

> **Finds the first character equal to one of the characters in the given character sequence.** Search begins at pos, i.e. the found character must not be in position preceding pos.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_first_of()`.

Here's a reference for the `std::string` methods. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string